# Magento 2 checkout input field remove CSS class

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento24, magento-checkout

I want to remove *control* css class and add custom css class.

[image]

Thanks advance!!

Comment: Why not just use CSS to override the current styles?

Comment: Because I need to design and re-structure checkout page.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change or add class in fields then you have to copy the file

`vendor\magento\module-ui\view\frontend\web\templates\form\field.html`

and move in your theme

`app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Ui\web\templates\form\field.html`

[image]

after the changes are done then you have to `deploy content` from the command line.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: When I change in this files it's affected to overall website. I just need this changes only on checkout page.